# C++ socket for windows and unix system

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, unix

I'm looking for an implementation of the socket in c + + (UDP/TCP).
This should work on Windows and UNIX systems.
suggest you know something good?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a comment but Boost [ASIO](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) library provides portable implementation of sockets. I've personally built boost for Windows which works for both Visual and gnu compilers. It also works on numerous other unix platforms. There is a decent description of how it works at http://boost.cowic.de/rc/pdf/asio_doc.pdf. The library itself also contains tutorials.

Edit: The license is also pretty good. My company is a stickler with third party software licenses (no GPL allowed) and they gave Boost a thumbs up which is pretty rare.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a tutorial:
http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/

If you're looking for a library:
http://www.alhem.net/Sockets/

If you're looking for a video:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-Uem2FzXXA
(the guy doesn't know what he's talking about, but it may help)

Otherwise, if you just want a custom lib, I may be able to help you (maaaybe)
-ultifinitus@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Enet](http://enet.bespin.org/). Works well for what I'm doing. It does reliable and unreliable UDP